# Create custom OAuth Login Page and custom jwt token

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jsp, oauth

I have created an OAuth Authorization Server using default spring boot configurations, where the client is redirected to the auto-generated login page, userDetailsService looks up the User table and authenticates, and after successful authentication the server returns a jwt token. Now I want customize this and change two things but I am having difficulty in doing it.

1) Use my own login.jsp page instead of the auto-generated login page so I can have an extra field(eg. dropdownlist) and use this along with the username and password for authentication since I have different user tables

2) Instead of using the default UserDetailsService I am trying to implement my own AuthenticationProvider, this is because I have multiple users table and want to search for user in the correct table based on the value from the extra field (dropdown list mentioned in 1). Also how to get the dropdownlist value in the AuthenticationProvider?

In my properties file I have set:
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/ and
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ServerWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new DefaultAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Import(ServerWebSecurityConfig.class)
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        JdbcClientDetailsService jdbcClientDetailsService = new JdbcClientDetailsService(dataSource);
        clients.withClientDetails(jdbcClientDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("secret");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```java
public class DefaultAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getName() == null || authentication.getCredentials() == null
                || authentication.getName().isEmpty() || authentication.getCredentials().toString().isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        final String userName = authentication.getName();
        final String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
        // final String userTable = how to get this?

        // make db query in correct table based on value of userTable
        User user = null;

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (UserAuthority authority : user.getUserAuthorities()) {
            authorities.add(new CustomGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority().getName()));
        }

        Map<String, String> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
        userDetails.put("username", userName);

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, authorities);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

```java
@Controller
public class OAuthController {

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

```
I am expecting that my client app is redirected to the custom login page, once login button is pressed my custom AuthenticationProvider will lookup for user in the correct table based on the extra field in the custom login page.
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first point you just have to configure your custom login-path for the login in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Add `.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()`

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers()
        .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: hello yes thank you it worked, initially I had the form login but now realized that I was missing a dependency as a result the JSP file was not being rendered.